# Update one table based on another table automatically in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm coding a website. My question can be simplified to this:

If there is a transaction happened and recorded in the transaction table. The balance table should be updated automatically based on the transaction.

One way I could think of is that adding another column in the transaction table as a flag to see whether the balance table has been updated based on this transaction. Each time a user opens the website, I would use php to update the balance table with the entries flagged as "not updated" in the transaction table and then display the updated balance table.

But that means every time the balance table is updated once a user is checking the balance.

The approach that I update both tables when I insert the transaction table is not feasible because I only have the access to the database of the transaction, not the code to insert.

I wonder if there is any other way that the balance table can be updated automatically based on the transaction table? Is there a script that can be put on the server side to run every 10 seconds or a push function whenever there's an update in the transaction table then the server would update the balance table automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @weeo how is the Data Access layer coded in your application ... does every DataAccess happen thru stored procedures or does it happen thru a ORM or direct table access ? Pls clarify.

Comment: @objectNotFound The transaction table is from another datasets, it will push new data into my datasets that have the same transaction table.. so i need to update my balance table based on the updated transaction table. So i can do anything about my own tables. But the transaction table is updated via push function from another database.

Comment: from what you have said you cant change the transaction table schema without modifying the external push mechanism as that will break. Unless the table is accessed via stored procedures and views. If inserts are done thru a SP it is straightforward to handle your situation.

Answer (score 3):

The first question is, do you want a balance table at all?  If you can derive balances from transactions, maybe a view would suffice.  It would always be up to date, and imposes no overhead or complexity to transaction processing.

If you want to cache derived balances in a table -- perhaps because balances are viewed much more often than transactions are added -- you need to be able to do that from a cold start.   You don't want to be in the position of being able to generate a balance only when a transaction arrives, because when something goes wrong -- not if, *when* -- you'll be stuck writing "emergency code" when you'd rather be having dinner.  So don't make balance-generation depend on transaction processing.

Here's how I would do it:

- Write a balances view.
- Create a `balances` table identical to the view, but with a column `last_transaction_time`.

Now you need an SQL procedure to do the following:

1. Compare `max(balances. last_transaction_time)` to  `max(transactions.time)`.
2. If `balances` is out of date, update it from the view.
3. `select ... from balances` (table).

The downside is that the user will have to wait for balances to be regenerated after new transactions are posted.  The upside is balances are generated only when needed, not after every transaction.  That's usually very important, because transaction processing is often time-sensitive.

There will always be *some* time between processing transactions and computing balances.  The utility of caching the balance is a function of the its frequency of use and complexity of computation.

The above process always produces correct balances and minimizes the number of computations.  It could be modified to "pre-compute" out-of-date caches during slack time; that would be a choice to incur off-peak overhead in exchange for peak-time throughput.

Comment: +1 for `The upside is balances are generated only when needed, not after every transaction.` The point of having a balance table in the first place is to display to someone the current balance, and if no one is asking, why calculate it?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm also thinking about not having the balance table and calculate the balance every time from transaction table. But my transaction table can become very large. So I think keeping a balance table would better to speed up the process...Thank you for your detailed plan. I would go this way!